# Which tanks will be removed from my garage?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I have played World of Tanks casually since beta, and I like to keep a lot of tanks. In particular, I've collected handful of premium tanks via various promotions, which I rarely use, but which I like to keep nevertheless.

During my play time, a lot of tanks have been removed from the game for various reasons. Some times, these tanks are replaced by others, some times not.

I can see that a few of my (premium) tanks are no longer available in the game, but are still in my garage.

After seeing in-game chats and searching the forum (evidenced by the link in Chantola's answer), players seem to know ahead of time, which tanks will be removed from the game entirelly.

Where is this information available? Can I see it in-game somehow? Or is it simply hearsay and case-by-case?

Comment: I'm unsure of how we would be able to answer the first part; it would require us to be able to see into the future.  The second part, though, could be answered by what happened when someone got a tank removed from their garage.

Comment: It is certainly answerable. Perhaps there's a warning icon somewhere, or maybe Wargaming writes in in their wiki or news section before removal. "No, there is no way to tell" is also an answer. The second part is more complicated, since the compensation is irregular – but if there is a removal list or similar, I would guess they would also write about possible compensations.

Comment: I'm sorry, but no.  The first part is pure speculation, and is off-topic all by itself.  Anything that requires us to go hunting for what a developer has said is also off-topic, because we're not a news site.  Like I said, the second part is something that has probably happened, and we can answer that based on previous actions.  But I'd recommend removing the first part, because we can't answer that, and falls into at least two different off-topic categories.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I'm not asking you to look into your crystal ball. I want to know if the developer regularly announces ahead of time, which tanks are to be removed, and where that information can be found. Forum posts suggest players already know which tanks are to be removed in future updates. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Again, that's asking us to go find developer information for you, which we don't do; Arqade explicitly does not allow questions that require a developer to have talked about in order for us to answer.  That's because Arqade isn't a news site, and comes with lots of other problems attached to just repeating what developers have said.  It's a very problematic area, because we can't guarantee what the developer is saying is even correct (XBone always online comes to mind).  Much better to be able to point to something we can use and test to be able to answer questions.

Comment: Is it alright if I ask for in game solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

News on tanks getting replaced / removed usually come from the test servers where changes are made ahead of time to be trialed. People on test servers also tend to get some inside info.  The only tanks to be completely removed are ones from special events. Otherwise you tend to get a like for like replacement. If a premium tank is removed from sale everyone who has it still keeps it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solutions other than third-party news sites are patch notes in the news feed on the game launcher and/or the game website. Test servers give a look at the patches before they hit and their changelogs are useful for getting advance warning as well. I don't believe any premium tank has gotten majorly changed or replaced other than the Super Pershing, which had an armor and mobility change with the opportunity to sell it for its purchase price in gold.

Tanks on the tech tree occasionally get changed, but of late it's just been a matter of getting the top tier tank of the split with a roughly approximate set of modules on it, so it's not really worth knowing about ahead of time unless it will make a grind harder. I can't think of a tank which has been removed from the game entirely, although the Type 59 and of late the Su-76i have been removed from sale.

Answer (score 0):

The first part to the question, nobody really knows. As Frank said, that would require us to see in the future.

But if this does happen to you, and you lose a tank:

> you will get a model swap with camo, equipment and consumables refunded, sent to depot. crew directly transferred to the new vehicle with no changes to crew skills.not sure if crew are a bit different though.

So you should not worry so much about losing tanks.

**Source:** http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/213269-t-50-2-soon-gone-what-should-i-do/

Comment: The post you are linking to suggests that the OP already knows the tank will be removed. I am interested in knowing where this information comes from.

Comment: @Nix you can find this information in upcoming updates and patch notes, on the official website.